# "Suspend" and Nvidia problems in fresh Debian Stable install

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, suspend, nvidia

I have recently installed Debian11-XFCE (fresh install). It is working very well but is giving trouble in "suspend" function.

When I used to click "Suspend" in XFCE logout panel in Debian10 (previous version), the  computer would quickly make screen blank and power button would convert from "continuous on" to "blinking".

In this fresh install, on clicking "Suspend", the computer display becomes blank immediately but the power button takes a long time to go to blinking mode. Also, on pressing space bar to resume, there are 5-6 line error messages on text screen (each line has "nouveau" in it) and then the computer freezes and I have to do a hard reboot.

The error is shown in this [photo](https://ibb.co/QFswGVZ).

My graphics information (from inxi) is as follows:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVA8 v: 3.3 Mesa 20.3.5
```

I have 4Gb RAM and about 8Gb swap in this desktop.

What could be the cause of this problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

***Edit:***

I see that I have got Nvidia card GeForce 210

I tried installing Nvidia driver using following command as given [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#bullseye-390).

```
sudo apt install nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver firmware-misc-nonfree
```

However, it is not working. The graphics part of inxi command output is:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: nouveau,vesa 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 1024x768 
  OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A
```

If I try to enter any file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "My GPU"
    Driver "nvidia"
EndSection
```

or

Section "Device"

```
Identifier "n"
Driver "nouveau"
EndSection
```

The display freezes at startup after giving errors/warnings in red color like:

```
FAILED: not able to start load kernel modules
FAILED: not able to start nvidia persistence daemon
```

So now I am worse off than where I began (nouveau was driver for nvidia card at fresh install- as shown in output of inxi in my first post above) since now there is no driver for nvidia card.

Though the display (including videos) is still working, the maximum display is 1024x768 (and not 1600x900).

Regarding the Suspend problem: it goes into suspend promptly but crashes on wake up.

Edit: I removed all nvidia files and reinstalled nouveau which is working all right but the Suspend problem is still persisting.

How can this problem be solved? Thanks for your help.