# "Suspend" etc not working after Debian-11 fresh install

Tags: linux, debian, suspend, nvidia

I have installed the new Debian-11 (with XFCE) on a desktop and it is otherwise working very well. However, the "Suspend" is not working properly.

Earlier with Debian-10 on same desktop, on pressing Suspend, the screen would go blank,  the disk activity would stop and the power light would go from continuous on to slow blinking state. On pressing the space bar, the desktop would awaken promptly to same state.

However, with new Debian-11 install, on pressing Suspend, the screen goes blank, but the disk activity and the power light remains continuously on. Also, on pressing space bar to resume, the display does not appear and I have to do a hard reboot. On rebooting, the messages include `recovering journal` for this partition and many `clearing orphaned nodes` messages.

Almost exactly same things happen if I press "Hibernate" or "Hybrid Sleep" buttons on xfce logout panel.

This desktop has a Nvidia card with nouveau as the driver. The graphics information from  `inxi --full` command is as follows:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVA8 v: 3.3 Mesa 20.3.5
```

What could be the cause of this problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: What does the syslog contain?

Comment: /var/log/syslog is a large file. What exactly should I check there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Suspend" and Nvidia problems in fresh Debian Stable install](https://superuser.com/questions/1703434/suspend-and-nvidia-problems-in-fresh-debian-stable-install)

Comment: There is no answer there. The problem has been persisting and I forgot I had posted it earlier. Will delete one of these soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to necrobump but as I am in the exact same situation (S3 which does not working with the **nouveau** driver on a **nVidia GeForce 210** GPU on the same system with XFCE too) and as I found a workaround, I propose to you to describe it here.

To make **nouveau** allows the S3 in disabling the **init_on_alloc** kernel parameter ([source](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213617#c6)) :

```
root@host:~# grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet init_on_alloc=0"
```

Note 1 : this parameter enable heap memory zeroing on allocation by default (more [here](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON.html))

Note 2 : the same was tested with success too with a **nVidia GeForce 8400GS 256MB DDR2** card

In my case the **nouveau** driver is working perfectly and I can use the suspend to RAM functionnality.

Comment: Good job! The only option I had was to remove nVidia graphics card.